# How come my SKSpriteNode is not appearing at the image's default resolution?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit

I have an image with a base resolution of 960 x 119 (base_ground_sprite) that I am trying to get to run across the bottom of my screen in the debugger.  When I run the debugger, however, it appears scaled to a larger size and therefore fuzzy.

I am an absolute novice here trying to work with the new Sprite Kit and could use some help.

As a note, the base of this code is from Ray Wenderlich's tutorial on sprite kit.

The following takes place in MyScene.m:

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {    
if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

    NSLog(@"Size: %@", NSStringFromCGSize(size));

    self.backgroundColor = [SKColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0];


    self.player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"player"];
    self.player.position = CGPointMake(self.player.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2);
    [self addChild:self.player];

    self.ground = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"base_ground_sprite"];
    self.ground.position = CGPointMake(0,0);
    self.ground.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
    [self addChild:self.ground];

    self.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0,0);
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self;

}
return self;
```

}

Comment: try with different scene scale modes: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKScene/scaleMode

Comment: is your resource image have @2x at the end ? If you use the test code of the spaceship when you make a blank SK project the ship looks junk, put 2x on the end and much better.

Comment: I tried using @2x but it doesn't look like it changed anything.  I'll search through the documentation some more.  I suppose learning Cocos2D would be an option but I was hoping to play around with Sprite Kit some more...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line `self.player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"player"];` to

```
self.player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"base_ground_sprite"] size:CGSizeMake(960, 119)];
```

This simply manually sets the size.